# How to listen for sliding up or down about LazyColumn

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)) {
        Column() {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.bgColorSecondary)),
                //控制item间隔的
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                state = scrollState
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(data ?: emptyList()) { index: Int, item: T ->
                    Surface(elevation = 1.dp) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)

                        ) {
                            content(index, item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isScrollToBottom.value) {
                println("加载更多!")
                Text(text = "加载更多")
            }
        }
        PullRefreshIndicator(
            refreshing = isRefreshing,
            state = pullRefreshState,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        )
    }
```

I want to know whether to slide up or down when sliding LazyColumn, not base item distance,but there is any slight upward or downward sliding